# Copy files within the pod filesystem after start

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another folder after start:

```
  containers:
    - image: my-image
      name: app
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-files
          mountPath: /var/folder1
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r /temp/. /var/fodler1"]
```

But for some reason files are not copied. When I am executing directly in the pod this command

```
/bin/sh -c "cp -r /temp/. /var/fodler1"
```

everything works fine.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any error message in the logs with that command while starting the pod?

Comment: try executing command from inside a bash script. It should work. Sometimes, these command behave stragely due to different reasons.

Comment: Is `folder` spelled the same way in both places?  Can you do this work in an entrypoint wrapper script in your image, or `COPY` the content into the image without using a volume mount at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes in my code folder is spelled correctly, just make a typo here

Comment: Can you see anything in events when you `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` ? As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#debugging-hook-handlers) if `PostStart` handler fails for some reason, it should be reflected in events.

Comment: @mario nothing there :(

Comment: Might be a race condition between postStart lifecycle and when the volume is attached and available. Try putting a `sleep 10;` before `cp`